# get GCP patch compliance details for VMs via Rest API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to retrieve patch compliance details of a specific VM via rest APIs.
I have tried below API which gives compliance details against a given patch.

```
GET https://osconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/abc/patchJobs/patch01/instanceDetails
```

But I need to get VM wise compliance details.

Comment: Have you looked at this API? https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management/manage-patch-jobs#retrieve-compliance-data

Comment: @CaioT yeah i checked it. but it doesn't have any data related to patch upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

To get the patch job status for a given VM instance apply [filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) to the API mentioned in the question.
Also refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list?apix_params=%7B%22project%22%3A%22concise-forge-315014%22%2C%22zone%22%3A%22us-central1-a%22%2C%22filter%22%3A%22name%3Dinstance-4%22%7D#query-parameters) to know about filters.

API to get patch job status for a given VM instance:   [https://osconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/`](https://osconfig.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/%60)<ProjectID/ProjectNumber>`/patchJobs/<`PatchJobID`>/instanceDetails?filter=name%3D<`instance-name`>

Find the screenshots below to see the difference between responses when applying a filter and when not.

[image: curl - Patch job status of all instances]
[image: curl - Patch job status of given instance]
[image: Tool - Patch job status of all instances]
[image: Tool - Patch job status of given instance]

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: sorry for the late response. This is clear. i tried this earlier as well. When it comes to AWS and AZURE they are giving each vm's compliance status separately.( not against a patch deployment directly). I'm just checking whether GCP also has the same capability to get patch Compliance details directly(not against a specific patch deployment)?